# python ete3 - failure to create pdf after Gtk warning

Tags: python, render, phylogeny, ete3

I have run into a problem that I do not find any helpful information on. I am using ete3 in python to automatize the creation of phylogenetic tree figures. I have written some code that works wonderful if I execute it in my ipython notebook.

However, when I run it in the terminal via `python script.py`, I get the following warning message:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:7657): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

After the warning appears, the code is just stuck and does not create the figure.I already tried updating the glib library, but it did not help.

The code I am using is:

```
def my_layout(node):
    F = TextFace(node.name, tight_text=True)
    add_face_to_node(F, node, column=0, position="branch-top")
    if node.is_leaf():
        seq_face = SeqMotifFace(node.sequence, seqtype='nt', seq_format='compactseq')
        add_face_to_node(seq_face, node, column=0, position='aligned')

def phylo_with_alignment(tree, alignment, out_dir, out_format):
    t2=PhyloTree(tree, alignment)
    t2.link_to_alignment(alignment=alignment, alg_format='fasta')
    ts2=TreeStyle()
    ts2.show_leaf_name=False
    ts2.layout_fn=my_layout
    print 'trying to render...'
    t2.render(out_dir.rstrip('/')+'/'+os.path.basename(tree)+'phylo_aln.'+out_format, tree_style=ts2)
    print 'Done!'

try:
    parse_fasta(args.alignment)
    phylo_with_alignment(tree, alignment, args.out_dir, args.out_format)
    print 'Tataaaa, phylogeny with alignment created and saved to %s!' % out_dir
except Exception, e:
    print 'EXCEPTION: %s, line %s' % (e, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno)
    sys.exit()
```

The goal here is to create the figure and save it to `out_dir`. The Error occurs when I call `t2.render()`, before that everything runs smoothly.

Has someone an idea what I could do to fix this? I already looked at [How can I fix this error? Gtk-WARNING **: GModule ... initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963373/how-can-i-fix-this-error-gtk-warning-gmodule-initialization-check-faile) and connected questions, but could find no answers.

---

**EDIT:**

---

calling `conda remove glib` gets rid of the error message, but the script does still not finish.
**NOTE:** The same code is working when executed in an ipython notebook